# TBB upgrade: What happened to my bookmarks?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

I have just upgraded to the Tor Browser Bundle version 3.5.  I overwrote my old Tor directory, which normally preserved my bookmarks.  With this upgrade, all of my bookmarks are gone. Is there anyway to restore them?

Comment: most easy for me was export bookmarks from old version to html. open new bundle and import from html. all bookmarks were there again.

Comment: I have the same problem with the most recent upgrade of the Tor browser - unfortunatley all my bookmarks were overridden (disappeared) with the new upgrade. I really need those bookmarks, one in particular! I am a relative newbie when it come to computer navigation - can you walk me through the steps of how to restore my previous version of Tor so I can get my bookmarks back?

Answer (score 6):

The folder-structure between version 2.X and 3.X has changed. While the bookmarks were stored in

`\Tor Browser2.X\FirefoxPortable\Data\profile`

they are now stored in

`\Tor Browser3.5\Data\Browser\profile.default`.

You better create a new folder for the new TorBrowserBundle and then copy the bookmarks over.

It is recommended to export the bookmarks, unpack the new bundle to a different or new folder, import the bookmarks and then remove the old bundle.